Can I water wash my laptop keyboard?
There is a lot of dirty dust went into my keyboard or near it. I opened my laptop and try to took the keyboard off. But turns out it's welded on the panel, so I took off the panel and wondering if I can just water wash that? I mean the problem is that there is probobly chips for the keyboard and touchpad, so will it be fine if I just dry them after I wash them? I mean the chip is suppose to be solid and water can't get into there right?

Why hasn't anyone mentioned 99% isopropyl?  You can pick up a gallon at your local hardware or hydroponics store.

Thats probably not a great idea. In theory completely pure water should be fine but there's better ways to do it.
There's products that are essentially keyboard cleaning 'slime' - Colourcoral is one brand, and the brand I use is called cyberclean, that have dust, dirt and other gunk stick to them without needing to dismantle your keyboard.
ZDnet has an article that shows how to use it, but you just push it against your keyboard and knead it periodically to sort of get a fresh/less concentratedly dirty bit.
You might also want to consider compressed air or canned air to just blow it off or a vacuum cleaner (maybe with a sock on the hose so it dosen't suck in things it shouldn't.
"Dirty" keyboards are hardly worth the effort of a full dismantle, and generally unless you know exactly what you're doing, modern machines are not designed to be washed

I'm happy with in theory
